# What licenses the omission of an article in a countable or singular noun phrase?

Tags: grammar, idioms, nouns, articles, prepositional-phrases

Specifically, the term **market** in the following sentence is often referred to as "**the market**". But here the article has been omitted. What licenses such usage?

> The difference between prices in America and those in Europe was enormous, and planters were convinced that the reason for this was that Virginia and Maryland were dependent upon foreign shippers to carry their tobacco **to market**.

Source: [Novus Ordo Seclorum](https://kansaspress.ku.edu/978-0-7006-0311-4.html)

Comment: "Market", in the example, is uncountable. This use arises in a restricted number of cases where the noun is well-established institution or large location of some sort. The slave was sent to market/jail/hospital/sea, etc. The uncountability equates to the general concept of anywhere through which the sale of goods/imprisonment/medical care/the occupation of sailor, etc. can be achieved. -- **The**" is basically a demonstrative adjective and, in broad terms, implies that the noun is a specific place of which the listener is aware and/or has been defined.

Comment: @Greybeard "The slave was sent to *the* hospital" for North American speakers.

Comment: Compare "sent to bed" and "sent to the table". It's not particularly logical.

Comment: @Greybeard Whether it's a count or non-count noun is a non-issue here. The same _prison_ can be used without _the_ when we describe an inmate (_he went to prison_) but with _the_ when we describe a non-inmate (_he went to the prison to visit a friend of his_). It's unnecessarily complicated to hypothesize the same _prison_ can be a count or a non-count noun depending on the subject of the sentence. Moreover, non-count nouns can have _the_ as in _he bought the furniture_, _the information was not available_, etc.

Comment: @JK2 *Whether it's a count or non-count noun is a non-issue here.* It must be as a singular count noun cannot be used without a determiner as in "to prison" and "to a prison" and "to the prison" have different meanings.

Comment: @GArthurBrown *"The slave was sent to the hospital"* Thanks for the reminder. It does seem strange to me as a BE speaker where my first thought when hearing this would be "Which hospital?", although, inexplicably this does not occur if I hear "He was sent to the supermarket."

Comment: @Greybeard It does seem to be somewhat arbitrary. You can go to church, but even if you are a monk/nun you have to go to **the** monastery, **the** nunnery, **the** convent.

Comment: @Greybeard But the OP's specifically asking about why _the_ is being omitted, not about why _a_ is being omitted. Even if _market_ were a non-count noun, the question still remains unanswered, because, as pointed out earlier, non-count nouns can have _the_.

Comment: @JK2 *But the OP's specifically asking about why the is being omitted,* Yes, and I told him that this was permissible with uncountable nouns.

Comment: @Greybeard I wonder whether this usage of "to market" is licensed at all. The writer is evidently an American historian.  In American usage, "brought to market" or "sent to market" is a expression with a somewhat abstract meaning that encompasses the entire process of a good being made available for purchase on some market.  That is, we don't use the uncountable "market" the same way Brits might.  "Carried to market," to mean literally transported, while evidently sensible in BrE, strikes me as a misuse of the relatively fixed and abstract expressions above in a U.S. environment.

Comment: @cruthers "carry to market" has a long established usage in American English, though it has become far less common than it was in the 19th Century. I would say that "Virginia and Maryland were dependent upon foreign shippers to carry their tobacco to *the* market" doesn't work. We are talking about transporting goods in order to be sold, rather than a specific location.

Comment: @GArthurBrown What is your source?  N-grams?

Comment: @cruthers You can get an overview from the [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=carry+to+market%2Ccarried+to+market%2Ctransport+to+market%2Ctransported+to+market&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3#). It's hard to search all the possible combinations of "carry X to market" though.

Comment: Ah.  I've got separate problems with n-grams, but in any case wouldn't rely on n-grams for this.  Results could reflect 19th century American use of article-less "market" per the Brits.  You'll also note the non-Fedex approved use of "shippers" by this author in the same sentence.  He could have written: "...planters in Virginia and Maryland were dependent upon foreign carriers when shipping their tobacco."  Mainly just thinking the usage through. I don't find the original writing particularly objectionable and probably would not have noticed anything amiss.

Comment: @Cruthers And expanding on that "planters in Virginia and Maryland were dependent upon foreign carriers when shipping their tobacco **to market.**" seems perfectly idiomatic to my American ears.

Comment: @cruthers I think your idea of the abstract non-count "market" is very well expressed, and better than I managed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may not be possible to define a rule here. What matters is what is idiomatic.

In English, *[to be sent to market](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22sent%20to%20market%22&client=firefox-b-1-d&ei=_cDqYMKROMvR-wTK2bHoBw&oq=%22sent%20to%20market%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMggIABAWEAoQHjIICAAQFhAKEB4yCAgAEBYQChAeMggIABAWEAoQHjIFCAAQhgMyBQgAEIYDMgUIABCGAzIFCAAQhgM6BwgAEEcQsAM6BQgAEJECOgsILhDHARCvARCRAjoICC4QxwEQowI6BQgAELEDOggIABCxAxCDAToLCC4QsQMQxwEQowI6AggAOggILhCxAxCDAToCCC46BQguELEDOggILhDHARCvAToLCC4QsQMQxwEQrwE6BAgAEApKBAhBGABQ5_wCWISWA2DcmANoAnABeACAAfsDiAGfHZIBCzAuOC42LjIuMC4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiChMr64NrxAhXL6J4KHcpsDH0Q4dUDCA0&uact=5)* means to be offered for sale **on** the market. This is an abstract concept. The market has no physical location. This may occur in multiple places. ["Around 85% of ducklings would survive this eight-week rearing process to be sent to market."](https://ludwig.guru/s/to+be+sent+to+market)

*to be sent to the market*  is used in contexts like "My mother sent me to the market to buy eggs." This means being sent to buy eggs **at** the market. This is a physical location. There is a particular marketplace in mind.

This is also used in economics in circumstances like: ["What signal is sent to the market when a firm decides to issue new stock to raise capital?"](https://study.com/academy/answer/what-signal-is-sent-to-the-market-when-a-firm-decides-to-issue-new-stock-to-raise-capital-a-bond-markets-are-overpriced-b-bond-markets-are-underpriced-c-stock-price-is-too-low-d-stock-price-is-too-high.html) This is saying the something is being communicated to an area of the economy ([4d: MW.com: the area of economic activity in which buyers and sellers come together and the forces of supply and demand affect prices](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/market)). Note: this does not mean that something is being offered for sale on the market.

There is no hard-and-fast rule for how to determine when the article is used in English, and the rules even vary within different varieties of English: The Brits can say "sent to hospital" while North Americans have to say "sent to the hospital." But we both say "sent to school" meaning that the person is enrolled for education at an academic institution. (While being sent to **the** school means being sent to the physical location of the school building.)

Comment: Or even "for sale on market"? :)

Comment: @JK2 I can only say that would never be said in American English. "For sale on **the** market" always. "

Comment: Exactly the reason why I brought it up. Now, you'd have to distinguish between the possible "to market" and the impossible "on market". Good luck.

Comment: @JK2 I'm not following you at all.

Comment: I mean, I couldn't agree more with your first paragraph. You can't possibly find a consistent rule here. Even your own attempt at it ("market" being an abstract concept, etc.) involves the phrase "on the market", where you can't omit "the". Go figure.

Comment: As mentioned in my comment below the main answer, I agree with your answer but believe it suggests that the author of the excerpt is not particularly licensed to use "to market" this way.

Comment: @cruthers This is the main answer.

Comment: @GArthurBrown True.